# How to add Firebase Cloud Messaging to an existing Analytics Account apps

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've got an existing google analytics account with several properties/apps. I'm wanting to add Firebase Cloud Messaging to all the existing analytic account apps.

I've tried:

- creating a new Firebase Account
- project settings / integrations / enable google analytics
- Selected existing Google analytics account
- Under analytics property, trying to select an all or one existing property/app but they are all disabled/grayed out

Any idea why they would be disabled? Is it a permissions issue on the analytics side?

Appreciate your help.
-MCore